# How can integer be appended to string if + '0' is provided

Tags: c++, string, append, std

I encountered with a strange code in a solution of a programming problem and I couldn't find any good idea about it. Here,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int count=8;
    string temp="Hello ";
    temp+=count+'0';
    cout<<temp;
    return 0;
}
Output is: Hello 8
```

integer variable count was appended to the string even without type casting the integer variable. I guess it worked because of '0' but what is this process or method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> integer variable count was appended to the string even without type
> casting the integer variable.

No, no integer variable was appended. The only suitable overload for the `+=` operator is the one that takes a single `char` parameter, and ends up adding a single character to the string. The integer value type gets converted to a `char` type, and the rest is history.

So, adding 8 to the character `'0'` produces, unsurprisingly, character `'8'`. Things, of course, go in an exciting direction if your integer variable is negative, or greater than 9. You should try it, the results should be illuminating.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler will do an implicit conversion to resolve the

```
temp+=count+'0';
```

It can be interpreted like this for better understanding

```
temp.operator+=(static_cast<char>(count + static_cast<int>('0')));
```

So the ascii value of `0` will be added to `count` and that will be `56` in decimal which will be converted back to ascii `8`.
The `operator +=` overloaded for `char` will be triggered with `8` as it's argument.

You can even convert your 3 lines like the below code and you will still get the same result.

```
int count=56;
string temp="Hello ";
temp+= count;
```

Comment: well, no. It might be converted to some equivalent of that, but the compiler will not first generate that (intermediate) C++ code...

Comment: @JHBonarius : I have pasted the intermediate code which was generated by https://cppinsights.io/ May be different compilers will resolve it differently. But this is a correct one for one of the compilers.

Comment: CppInsights is /not/ a compiler, but an interpreter based on the clang compiler. It visualizes what is happening internally. The actual clang compiler is doing thing with an internal representation (AST leading to IR, etc)

Comment: @JHBonarius: So the compiler will never do the casting? I agree to the point that there will be no intermediate code generated like this. I will modify my answer a bit.

Comment: The compiler will not do an implicit cast; there is no such thing. The compiler will do an implicit **conversion**. A **cast** is something you write in your source code to tell the compiler to do a conversion. A cast is always explicit.

Comment: @PeteBecker: thanks for correcting my language . but I want to say the same a conversion. Do you also agree to same that compiler will never convert the code to an equivalent of `temp.operator+=(static_cast<char>(count + static_cast<int>('0')));` ?